# Bitcoind stopped working

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, server

Hello i have been running Bitcoind and Dogecoind for more than 2 month and all has been working great but today bitcoind has stopped working

I am receiving the error:

```
Warning: fopen(http://...@127.0.0.1:3333/): failed to open stream: Connection refused
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to connect to http://bitcoin:pass@127.0.0.1:3333/' in /script/jsonRPCClient.php:140
```

I have disabled firewall but still am receiving the error

Bitcoin.conf

```
server=1
daemon=1
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=pass
rpcport=3333
port=3334
txindex=1
```

Thanks

Comment: Any chance the port 3333 is closed? Also what happens if you try navigating to the URL that is in the error?

Comment: I switch iptables policy to ACCEPT but not work. With url i have 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED' message. I tested with other port but nothing `fopen(http://...@127.0.0.1:3633/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
 in /example.com/jsonRPCClient.php on line 132`

Comment: i think the probleme is from sendtoaddress() because getnewaddress() work

Comment: Humor me and try typing "curl http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:3333/" and let me know what you receive.

Comment: There's probably something relevant in your `debug.log` file.  Have you checked?

Comment: Thanks for reply all, i installed new version and reindex chain and now all work fine

Comment: Problem is not stated clearly enough to be answered, also asker has resolved his problem and probably isn’t interested anymore. Placing it on hold.